# How to change content of a specific div that has data-attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know how I can change the content of a specific div that has data attribute.

I am using a click event and .html

I have many div elements as follows:

```
<div class"name-of-class" data-user-id="ID">Content that changes</div>
```

I already have the ID variable to identify what div I need to change

```
$('.name-of-class').click( function() {
  $('.name-of-class').html('new content');
}
```

So, I want to use the data attribute data-user-id inside the click function to specify exactly what div I need to change.

I hope I am making myself clear, if not, I will try to explain myself better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Attribute Equals Selector [name="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

```
$('.name-of-class').click( function() {
  $('[data-user-id="id"]').html('new content');
}
```

**Edit**, based on comments, to pass variable

```
$('.name-of-class').click( function() {
  $('[data-user-id="'+ idVariable +'"]').html('new content');
}
```

Comment: Hello, I will ask the same question I asked @Satpal How can I pass a variable to the selector?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Attribute Equals Selector [name="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
$('.name-of-class').click( function() {
  $('.name-of-class[data-user-id="id"]').html('new content');
}
```

### EDIT

As per comment

```
$('.name-of-class').click( function() {
  $('.name-of-class[data-user-id="' + useridvariable +'"]').html('new content');
}
```

Comment: Hi, How can I pass a variable inside that selector? I have a variable called userId, so cna pass it like this: '[data-user-id=userId]' ?

Comment: @Gixty, Use `$('.name-of-class[data-user-id="'+ userid +'"]')` Simple string concatenation

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

HTML:

```
<div class="name-of-class" data-user-id="ID">Content that changes</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.name-of-class').click( function() {
   $(this).html('new content');
});
```

Comment: Hi, this will change all divs containing that class. I need to change only the div for that specific ID.